# Most Current Result

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that reports 3 number results by quarter. I would like to create a pie chart that will only use the most current information. For example it will use quarter 1 data if no other quarter is filled out, but it will use quarter 2 data instead of quarter 1 data if there is a number in that cell. And so on until quarter 4.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a "chart" column that is always what is charted.  In that column, you use a formula that selects the latest quarter.  For example, if quarters 1-4 are in columns A-D, starting in row 1, You could chart column E, and E1 would contain:

```
    =IF(ISBLANK(D1),IF(ISBLANK(C1),IF(ISBLANK(B1),IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1),B1),C1),D1)
```

Copy this down for all the rows you use.  Row 1 could be a Quarter label, which would then appear in E1, so the chart labeling could incorporate that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also accomplish this with a dynamic named range:

Suppose your data looks like this

```
    A       B       C       D
1   1st     2nd     3rd     4th
2   1.1     1.2     1.3     1.4
3   2.1     2.2     2.3     2.4
4   3.1     3.2     3.3     3.4
```

- Open the name manager and click "New..."
- Name your range something descriptive, and define it as  `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A$2:$D$2)-1,3,1)`   (Let's suppose you called it ***mostRecentData***
- Make a pie chart the way you always have.  (Select A2:A4 and Insert--> Pie Chart?
- Click on the pie.  In the formula bar, change the data reference from `Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4` to `Sheet1!mostRecentData`

Now your pie chart should display the rightmost of the four columns that has a value in row 2.

**Notes**

- You may wish to do something similar with the Chart Title.  Or you could calculate the title in a cell and refer to the cell from the graph.
- This will break if you miss a quarter's worth of data.  If that happens sometimes, you'll need a more sophisticated name definition, but this should get you started.
- If you calculate the column offset value in a cell instead of within the named range, you can set up a spinner to manually adjust it, so you can easily click through the quarters